# Math-stick problem

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

Here are 6 matchsticks.

[image: Matchsticks]

#### You should rearrange them, to make nothing

But you should not waste or get other matchsticks

Comment: lateral thinking?

Comment: @Oray What is lateral thinking? A Tag?

Comment: yes, it is pure math or requires some lateral thinking?

Comment: Yes it is not pure math, it requires some out-of-the-box thinking.

Comment: "5 matchsticks"? I see 6...!

Comment: @Stiv Sorry. number mistake.

Comment: "out-of-the-box thinking" - Does that mean we can use the matchbox to solve the puzzle? If so, it's easy.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica No only the mathchsticks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With all these mathematics going on, I have [nothing](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nix) to add:

> [image]

Comment: Why didn't I think about this? Nix means nothing in german too.

Answer (score 18):

I think this might be the answer you had in mind! This is I think is the most canonical of my attempts. No change in character size and only using basic arithmetic without repeating or "abusing" operations

> [image]

Here is one which makes use of powers and some "abuse" of operations.

> [image]

Here we get a little more abstract. Summing from 1 to 1, i.e. summing over an empty set, i.e. nothing!

> [image]

Here go further down the abstraction hole. An object that does not exist! $F_n$ is a common standard notation for the [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of $n$ elements. Here we have supposed the field of $\mathbb{V I}$ or 6 elements. But since 6 is a composite number that is not a power of primes, no such field exists!

> [image]

Comment: Nice answer. But there is still one more.

Comment: Just a question: Where did you get the editor you edited with the math-sticks?

Comment: I just used GIMP, its entirely free and open-source https://www.gimp.org/.

Comment: You could also do - 1 + a long1

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I don't see what you mean?, oh a "long 1. I don't like using the matchsticks to make mismatched sized characters, else we could make a big hexagon and call it zero.

Comment: Nit-pick: $\sum_1^1$ isn't really summing over the empty set; it's actually the single term corresponding to the index 1.

Comment: Good point! I always make this mistake by thinking of in terms of for loops.

Comment: Also you still have to have an expression inside the sum.

Answer (score 17):

Okay, because there are so many answers, here is what I thought:

> [image: nil]

> NIL means in maths 0

Comment: I was just about to post that :/

Comment: I actually think the mathematics tag is misleading/unfitting here. Nil is almost never used as zero in mathematics. It is very commonly used in sporting events, especially British ones.

Comment: @Mark Ok, I changed the tag

Comment: go language go language

Comment: @zixuan What does go language mean?

Comment: Go language. search it.

Answer (score 8):

> [image]

I think this works, I hope it is the right answer

If you break the match sticks

> [image]

Comment: Yes it works, but there is one more.

Comment: Please rotate this picture 90 deg to the right

Comment: Can someone help me edit this answer

Comment: You are really a deep-thinker! I thought of another one. But I did not think that there would be three answers for one question! Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks but I am not really a deep thinker compared to some the very smart fellows you find on here

Comment: Here is a 90 deg to right picture: https://imgur.com/Ti3EMxf

Answer (score 7):

Here's another

> [image]
>  |0| **or** *the absolute value of zero.*

Comment: I appreciate that you went to the effort of making the zero into Penrose stairs! +1

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I was going to change the orientation of the matches as well but it was taking me too long..

Comment: Dude they are not impossible, try them with your fingers. :)

Answer (score 6):

If we really want nothing, what could be better than

> the empty set!

> [image: the empty set]

Answer (score 2):

Could the answer be:

> **1 / 1 = 1 Means nothing!**
>
>
>  [image]

Comment: There are meant to be 6 matchsticks

Comment: @MarkMurray I didn't realize, thanks!

Comment: I think the author originally had 5 written down by accident

Comment: Mathematical identity is a cornerstone of algebra, so I'd hardly say that 1=1 means nothing - it is a vitally important foundation of mathematics.

Comment: @NuclearWang Yeah, but logically, it does :)